# Cat is having a freakout, what is wrong with her?

Tags: cats, behavior, health

My cat is about 10 to 11 years old now, and as of the recent weeks she's been trying to leave, never leaving the window, meowing significantly louder than her normal quiet meows, and she seems to barely eat and drink anymore.

Comment: Has she been spayed? Is she always indoors?

Comment: I think you should take her to the vet. Could be any number of things but because this is abnormal and new behavior, she should be seen by a veterinarian.

Answer (score 12):

If the behaviour of your cat changes you need to take her to a vet.

Changes in drinking/eating are a sign something is wrong with your cat.

Some cats can get more vocal if they have a medical problem while other cats get less vocal if they have medical problems.

If a cat is in pain it will often try to avoid jumping up or down from or to places it has used before.

Litterbox problems can be a sign your cat is in pain or is ill, so keep an eye on this if your cat stops using the litterbox or other changes when using it.

You need to take the cat to the vet if you see any of these signs of problems in your cat.